# How to align tabular data to the left with printf?

Tags: c, output, printf, conversion-specifier

Let us suppose that we want to display different values aligned in a tabular way, in C, using printf.

We can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char strings[5][10] = {"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4","Test5"};
    int ints[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    float floats[5] = {1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5};
    int i;
    printf("%10s%10s%10s\n","Strings","Ints","Floats");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%10s%10d%10.2f\n",strings[i],ints[i],floats[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, we have 5 strings, 5 ints, and 5 floats. At each line, I would like to display them aligned. This piece of code does this. However, the data is aligned to the right. We can see the result in the following image:

[image]

How can I do something like this, but aligning the data to the left?

Comment: Use the minus sign '-' in the format strings.

Comment: Did you read the docs? Use `%-10d`.

Comment: @DarkAtom. No, i didn't. I'm novice at programming in C and trying to learn by myself. Do yout have a reference for those docs that you mention?

Comment: man printf works in shell and google

Comment: @Zaratruta https://en.cppreference.com/w/c I use this reference. Of course, the authority goes to the C Standard, but its not a good tool for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the flag '-' in the format strings like

```
    printf( "%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Strings", "Ints", "Floats" );
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf( "%-10s%-10d%-10.2f\n", strings[i], ints[i], floats[i] );
    }
```

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 6 The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> '-' The result of the conversion is left-justified within the field. (It is right-justified if this flag is not specified.)